# Is it possible to find a remote IP address if I know the local IP address?

Tags: networking, mac, ip

I’m connected to a network with a VPN. I need to connect to a device on the same network with it’s remote IP but the only IP I can find is the local one.

Is there a way to find the remote IP of a device if we know the local IP and we are connected to the same network?

**Edit - Complementary information:**

I am away from home, and I use a VPN I set up to connect to my home network. The VPN I use route all ipv4 traffic through the VPN.I am able to access the HDD I connected to my router, and I am able to see the devices that are connected to the network. I want to access to a Mac Server, but apparently it doesn't work when using the local IP address. I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the device have an own remote IP at all? There is a chance that you are sharing same remote IP (VPN's one) and could not be connected outside VPN at all. If the device has a remote IP than it is probably known by device's owners from VPN or ISP configuration, agreement, etc or could be viewed by accessing any website showing client's from the device. If you are sharing same network and only know the device's local IP than I'm not sure if there is a software way to find remote one without accessing the device at all.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by local and remote IP here? Do you mean private (VPN) vs public (WAN) IPs? Why can't you connect via the local IP on the VPN?

Comment: @MaQleod I added some information. I hope this helps

Comment: To VPN in, you must know the remote network's WAN IP, surely? So then with that in mind you already have your answer. If what I have said doesn't make sense or isn't what you want, then your understanding of these technologies is flawed and it's difficult for us to help because of the terms you're using it's hard to identify exactly where you're flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Just based on the information you provided, which is none, the answer is no.

More than likely, another device on the network is forwarding a public IP to the internal private IP of the device.

Depending on your access to the device, you could look at the IP configuration of the network, as it might have the public IP listed.  It could be possible the public IP is in a configuration file of some kind.

In the end, without more information it is impossible to tell.  The best thing to do is talk to whoever administers that device to find out.

---

Based on the new information you provided, the reason you cant access access your Mac server is that it has no public IP address.  Your router is the *only* device with a public IP.  You say you are VPNed in, if this is true, then you should have complete access to your network.

There is still a lot of information missing from your setup.  You have provided no technical information at all.

Comment: I administer my own home network, I added some more information in my original post.

Comment: @Mehdi I added more to my answer, however you sill have provided no technical information on your set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to the machine, you want to find out the remote IP you can try calling a web service.

```
curl icanhazip.com
curl checkip.amazonaws.com
curl https://wtfismyip.com/text
```

If the machine is connected through a NAT, that won't help you that much in the way of connecting to the machine. You would need some kind of port forwarding set up.